# What is the problem with this ternary operator?

Tags: java

```
String stuff="TV";
String res=null;

stuff.equals("TV") ? res="Walter" : stuff.equals("Movie") ? res="White" : res="No result";
```

> IDE says "variable expected". I did not get it. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 4):

`?:` is an expression. You cannot have a standalone expression without a statement. Instead, you want to assign the variable `res` only once and use `?:` to determine its value:

```
final String res = stuff.equals("TV") ? "Walter" : (stuff.equals("Movie") ? "White" : "No result");
```

Nested ternary expressions are very difficult to read (if formatted badly). I suggest to split the nested expression into a top-level if-statement and an un-nested expression instead:

```
final String res;
if (stuff.equals("TV")) {
  res = "Walter";
} else {
  res = stuff.equals("Movie") ? "White" : "No result";
}
```

Or convert to a cascade of if-elseif statements, or with recent Java versions to a switch expression:

```
final String res;
if (stuff.equals("TV")) {
  res = "Walter";
} else if (stuff.equals("Movie")) {
  res = "White";
} else {
  res = "No result";
}
```

```
final String res = switch (stuff) {
  "TV" -> "Walter";
  "Movie" -> "White";
  default -> "No result";
}
```

Note that you can also extract a method to convert `stuff` into your result string:

```
private static String convertStuff(final String stuff) {
  if (stuff.equals("TV")) {
    return "Walter";
  }

  if (stuff.equals("Movie")) {
    return "White";
  }

  return "No result";
}

private static void main() {
  final String stuff = "…";
  final String res = convertStuff(stuff);
}
```

Comment: "Nested ternary expressions are very difficult to read" - I disagree strongly, when time is taken to format them nicely. (I agree that they're hard to read when formatted badly, mind you.) See https://gist.github.com/jskeet/65a9b61df3a3f3ceafd47ab30a7f3c89 for example. If each "? condition : result" is on a separate line, you can get a very concise and readable way of expressing what you want. (It's then easy to convert into a switch expression, too...)

Comment: Thank you for nice answer. I prepare OCA exam and i always see this kind of wierd questions :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Agree on "nicely formatted", but unfortunately, most of the time I see badly-formatted ones. Furthermore, precedence can be a problem (IIRC PHP does something very fishy with nested ternary expressions). With newer Java versions definitely a switch expression. I will update my answer to include "badly formatted" in either case :)

Comment: @knittl: I've rarely found precedence to be a problem here in either C# or Java. Switch expressions are great if your conditions are all centered around the same expression, but I still find a well-formatted nested conditional operator to be a useful tool to have available.